# Visual Studio Snippet to Complete a Method Declaration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

I need snippet that after writing for example :

```
private void Accelerate()
```

i click TAB and it will make :

```
private void Accelerate()
{

}
```

Is there such a snippet to download in VS 2012? If not how to make my own snippet like this? Is this possible ?

Comment: resharper will do similar to that

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new snippet as an XML file, and then import it into Visual Studio using Tools->Code Snippets Manager.  Here's an example of what you're looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>method</Title>
        <Shortcut>method</Shortcut>
        <Description>Code snippet for a method</Description>
        <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>modifier</ID>
                <ToolTip>Public/Private/Protected</ToolTip>
                <Default>private</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>type</ID>
                <ToolTip>Method return type</ToolTip>
                <Default>void</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>name</ID>
                <ToolTip>The method name</ToolTip>
                <Default>MyMethod</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$modifier$ $type$ $name$()
    {
    }
]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

After importing this, then if you type "method" and hit tab, you'll see the code snippet listed above inside the "Code" element:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
}
```

You have the option to change the method's access (private by default), return type (void), and name.

Comment: I think he doesn't want the whole as a snippet. He just want to get the open + close bracket with a TAB. Although he would just have to hit ENTER and open the bracket and you automatically get the close bracket. Then just one more ENTER he is there.

Comment: Even better: if he opens the bracket on the same line of the function, and then hits ENTER, he'll be there also. That's just two key strokes (three if we count the SHIFT needed for the bracket) instead of the TAB.

Answer (score 1):

This is very close to what you want: make the following settings change in Visual Studio: Go to Tools/Options... menu, in the TreeView select Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping and uncheck "Leave block on on single line". If you do this, then you have to just open the bracket, and when you press TAB right after that the close bracket will appear, and they'll be in a new line.

This is built-in Visual Studio feature, doesn't require ReSharper, or snippet (ok, snippets are built in too).